# App Links `legacy_failure` verification error on Android 12

Tags: android, android-deep-link, android-app-links

I have setup `assetlinks.json` and `AndroidManifest.xml` so that the desired App Links are verified in all previous versions of Android. However, the verification no longer works in Android 12 (currently Beta 2). `adb shell pm get-app-links <PACKAGE_NAME>` returns `legacy_failure`.

There seems to be [some changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/web-intent-resolution#android-app-link-verification-changes) for App Links verification in Android 12, but the documentation isn't very explicit about what needs to be changed and whether the change is backward compatible.

Comment: Works fine for me on Android 12 Beta 3 and even when putting scheme and host into one data tag. Maybe you just needed to give the request some time to complete?

Comment: I was facing same issue due to the different package name inside assertlink.json file. Make sure your package name will be same in assertlink.json file.

Answer (score 30):

Turns out that if you break

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" />
```

into 2 tags

```
<data android:scheme="http" />
<data android:host="www.example.com" />
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml`, the app link will get verified successfully on Android 12. This change also seems backward compatible on older versions of Android, even though the documentation didn't say so explicitly.

Comment: how to test this ??

Comment: Important note: In my case I had example.com added as the host (because that's how it's explained everywhere) but since I was redirecting all requests from example.com to www.example.com due to SEO reasons it didn't work until adding the www.

Answer (score 14):

I faced the same issue.

`sha256_cert_fingerprints` of debug & release keystore are different.

if you register only release fingerprints on `assetlinks.json`, the verification doesn't work on debug version. so `adb shell pm get-app-links <PACKAGE_NAME>` returns `legacy_failure.`

It will work if you add both fingerprints (debug & release) on `assetlinks.json`

Comment: how to add both fingerprint , like comma separated in sha256 array

Comment: @dastan Did you figure how to add both together?

Comment: Yes, we updated our sha256 in assetlinks.json, and use above command to check fingerprint, if your build is signed with same keystore which fingerprint you added in assetlinks.json, then it will work otherwise it will always give legacy_failure, and I used Android Studio Asset Link tool to verify and test deep link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71676088/6341943
This is how I added both the keys. and it started working for me. Thanks guys

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the other answers which detail the need to:

- ensure you are using the correct `sha256_cert_fingerprints` value for the type of build you are testing, noting that this may differ based on whether you are using a Debug or Release build
- use separate `scheme` and `host` data tags entries for your `intent-filter` definition

It is also important to ensure that your `intent-filter` with `android:autoVerify="true"` does not contain any **custom uri schemes** (i.e. `launch://myapp/screen`) since these can cause the verifier to fail.

A new `intent-filter` can be provided solely for the custom uri scheme in which you do **not** set the `autoVerify` flag to `true`.

Check logcat whilst running the following commands to confirm if verification is working, as per the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#auto-verification).

> adb shell pm verify-app-links --re-verify <PACKAGE_NAME>

Look for the term `IntentFilterIntentOp` where it will state if verification succeeded or failed, i.e.:

> I/IntentFilterIntentOp: Verification 23 complete. Success:true. Failed hosts:. [CONTEXT service_id=244 ]

If one or more of the `intent-filter` definitions cannot be verified you may see the following in Logcat instead:

> "D/ProcessState: Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument" and no mention of `IntentFilterIntentOp`

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out no custom scheme when autoVerify=true

Answer (score 5):

**What changed?**

As from Android 12 they have introduced a new way of checking for supported web domains.

Lower versions of android remain unchanged.

**How does verification in android 12 works?**

On installing the application android sends async requests to domains inside intent links to check if .well-known/assetlinks.json exists and is valid.

**How to generate assetlinks.json?**

I recommend using this tool google provides for generating that file. It can also check if assetlinks.json is present and setup correctly.
Generator: https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator

**Where to get SHA-256 form**?

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open your Project
3. Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)
4. Click on Refresh (Click on Refresh from Gradle Bar, you will see List
5. Gradle scripts of your Project)
6. Click on Your Project (Your Project Name form List (root))
7. Click on Tasks
8. Click on Android
9. Double Click on signingReport (You will get SHA1 and MD5 in Run Bar(Sometimes it will be in Gradle Console))
10. Select app module from module selection dropdown to run or debug your application

After you have generated .json file, at put it inside root of domain (.well-known/assetlinks.json).
I recommend opening it manually just to make sure.
https://my.domain.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

**Setting up Intent links in application**

To your AndroidManifest.xml add

```
<!-- Make sure you have explicitly set autoVerify to true -->
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
 <!-- If a user clicks on a shared link that uses the "http" scheme, your
     app should be able to delegate that traffic to "https". -->
<data android:scheme="http" />
<data android:scheme="https" />

<!-- Include one or more domains that should be verified. -->
  <data
          android:scheme="https"
          android:host="**my.domain.com**"
          android:pathPrefix="/test" />
</intent-filter>
```

**Manually test if intent link is working:**

You can run this command with your emulator running and it should open the application:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://my.domain.com/test?code=abcde"
```

**Manually test intent link**

1. Support the updated domain verification process

   **adb shell am compat enable 175408749 PACKAGE_NAME**
2. Reset the state of Android App Links on a device

**adb shell pm set-app-links --package PACKAGE_NAME 0 all**

3. Invoke the domain verification process

**adb shell pm verify-app-links --re-verify PACKAGE_NAME**

***After running this command, it is CRUCIAL to wait for at least a minute for app to verify your domain**.*

4. Review the verification results

**adb shell pm get-app-links PACKAGE_NAME**

The output of this command is similar to the following:

```
com.example.pkg:
ID: 01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef
Signatures: [***]
Domain verification state:
  my.domain.com: verified
  sub.example.com: legacy_failure
  example.net: verified
  example.org: 1026
```

After that you're good to go, your intent links will work on android 12 and lower.

**Final test to check if you have set up everything properly**
Run:

```
 adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://my.domain.com/test?code=abcde"
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations

Answer (score 4):

Tested on Android 12, all the points mentioned by Jadent are valid, however breaking data declaration in host and scheme doesn't really matters.

Also I was using a wildcard in the 'host' attribute

```
android:host="*.example.com"
```

That's supposed to be supported in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#multi-subdomain)

However when I run the domain verification process

```
adb shell pm verify-app-links --re-verify PACKAGE_NAME
```

I got a legacy_failure error :( even if the assetlinks.json was placed in the root domain as required.

If the host is explicit:

```
android:host="www.example.com"
```

I didn't have such issue.

Comment: Was assetlinks.json at the root domain directly without redirects? That turned out to be my problem. assetlinks.json was at www.example.com, and example.com redirected to www.example.com. The assetlinks.json file is required to be directly accessible without going through a redirect (for security reasons, according to the docs.)

Comment: Finally solved it, the problem was only in Android 12 and the solution was adding "www." in front of the link. The only problem now is that the link is first opened in a browser and then it switches to the app, not sure if this is the wanted behaviour but at least it works so good enough for me, thanks!

Comment: @CosminVacaru in the manifest where host is defined??

Comment: @AwaisSaifi yes, in my case i had <data android:host="example.com" /> and by changing it to <data android:host="www.example.com" /> it started working

Comment: @JimE-H Machan, I really don't know who you are, Your comment helped me a lot. Finally, the app link is auto-verified. I wish to have a coffee with you. Thanks a lot, man.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue before.

It turns out that I used Play App signing service. The `sha256_cert_fingerprints` should be the one printed in Play Console (Release > Setup > App integrity), not the one on my hand. In fact, Play console generates the assetlinks.json in the "App integrity" page.

Ref for Play App signing
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#web-assoc

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the solutions above but none of those worked for me. I only changed on silly thing just to test and it worked. May be it's an obvious requirement but I didn't know so writing it down to help the others.

sha256_cert_fingerprints should always be uppercase in assetlinks.json file. I copied it off the terminal with lowercase letters and it didn't work but after changing it to uppercase, working flawlessly now.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. I was initially getting

```
ID: xxxx
Signatures: [XX:XX:XX:XX]
Domain verification state:
  xxx.xxxxxxx.eu-central-1.on.aws: 1024.
```

In my https://xxxxxxxxxx/.well-known/assetlinks.json file I hosted on my domain, I put 3 Signatures, one from release, another from debug and the last from the playstore (So I dont know which did the magic). But What changed verification state to: 'verified' was running this `adb shell pm verify-app-links --re-verify package-name`  command and waiting for 1 minute. After that everything worked well.