# Deeplinking is not working in capacitor in Andriod & iOS mobile apps

Tags: cordova, deep-linking, hybrid-mobile-app, capacitor, android-deep-link

We have followed the deep linking as per the capacitor Deeplinking documentation below and then we checked to click on the deep links and it doesn't take us to the mobile app and the URLs are opening in the browser.

[https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

1. Created Site Association File and verified using  **Asset Links tool** and app linked successfully to the domain.
2. Also added the Intent Filters in the manifest file and gave the host as the website domain
3. Followed everything as per documentation and tried these in the **signed apk**

Please help us if any other solutions - For deep linking using a capacitor

Comment: Hi Ronanki, have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

make sure your assetlinks SHA256 match exactly with signing key used for each build variant (debug build/firebase distribution/playstore) has different SHA256.

you can write an array and add [some asstelinks so the each build like mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71676088/14896542)

And if you create production build on playstore, check your play console if there's error on deep link. My apps on android 12 & 13 only opened deeplink in browser, it just need to [verify the site ownership](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080).