# Android Studio App Links Assistant does not show and activity

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-manifest, android-app-links

I have some problems with app linking in the Flutter project so I want to use Android Studio App Links Assistant.

But in the first step "Add URL Mapping" the activity drop box is empty

[image: App Links Assistant]

My `main/AndroidManifest.xml` is in below :

```xml
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.sepano.mrAntik.mr_antik">
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:label="MrAntk" android:name="${applicationName}" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Make sure you explicitly set android:autoVerify to "true". -->
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- If a user clicks on a shared link that uses the "http" scheme, your
                     app should be able to delegate that traffic to "https". -->
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <!-- Include one or more domains that should be verified. -->
                <data android:host="app.mrantic.ir" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Add this -->
</manifest>
```

I need help to change any file to add URL mapping ability in my Android Studio App Link Assistant.