# Flutter deep links verified, but not opening from a web link

Tags: flutter, deep-linking

I can't seem to get deep links working in [flutter](/questions/tagged/flutter).  I've set up my app correctly because the adb test works (see images for the intent and adb command below).  Google play console verifies the deep links host (see image below) - which means my assetlinks.json file is available and correct at the domain... (at /.well-known/assetlinks.json). But yet, a link in a HTML file doesn't open the app, but the website.  The backend serves the assetlinks.json file through Laravel (nginx), but seems to redirect to a 404 page before the browser passes control to the app.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Driving me dilly....  What have I missed?

Comment: Have you looked at answers in a similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143836/android-app-link-not-working-in-android-12-always-opening-in-browser?rq=2

Comment: Hi  Yes, but searched through many many similar issues.  But I did notice one thing in that one that I can try - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was 2-fold: 1.) that I was using the locally run version rather than the one downloaded from the App Store - obviously the Sha256 did not match that in the assetlinks.json - silly of me not to think of that, and 2.) I think Google needed a day or two to catch up with cacheing my assetlinks file.