# How to create dynamic deeplink for Android 12 and later versions?

Tags: android, webview, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I am creating an android based webview application for example.com with Java.

After clicking on any link, if the application is installed, I want the relevant link to open in the application.
This process takes place for versions before Android 12. For example, if the user clicks on the link https://example.com/xyz/ in any browser, the relevant link opens in the application.

However, for Android 12 and later, links always open in the browser.

I have provided the necessary steps for Deep Link for Android 12 and later:

- 1-) Android Manifest Update
- 2-) Creating assetlinks.json File (Note: Testing was done with SHA256
  fingerprint created from .apk file. So, SHA256 fingerprint in json
  file was taken from apk file.)
- 3-) Distributing the assetlinks.json File on the Server
  (https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json)
- 4-) Checking the Accuracy of the assetlinks.json File
- 5-) Verifying Changes on Android

*Test Realized: Success Host example.com grants app...*

However, application redirection still does not occur for Android 12 and above. I looked through the links below and couldn't find a solution:

[Your Deep Links Might...](https://doordash.engineering/2022/01/25/your-deep-links-might-be-broken-web-intents-and-android-12/)

[Developer Android Tutorial Deeplink...](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks?hl)

[Android app link not working in...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143836/android-app-link-not-working-in-android-12-always-opening-in-browser)

...

---- AndroidManifest.xml ----

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <!--  - - -Deeplink-->
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" tools:targetApi="m">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:scheme="http"
            android:host="*example.com"
            android:pathPattern=".*" />
        <data
            android:scheme="https"
            android:host="*example.com"
            android:pathPattern=".*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- Deeplink- - -  -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.lib_name"
        android:value="" />
</activity>
```

---- MainActiviy.java ----

```
//...
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        String URL = "https://example.com";
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction()) && data != null) {
            String path = data.getPath();
            URL+=path;

        }
        webview.loadUrl(URL);
        //...
    }
```