# AppLinks on Android 12 - opens browser only

Tags: android, applinks, android-12

I have the following manifest code:

```
<activity
        android:name=".InterceptorActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Startup"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:host="www.mysite.com"/>

            <data android:pathPrefix="/myPage"/>
            <data android:pathPrefix="/myFavourites"/>
       </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

assetlinks.json looks ok and uploaded correctly. But all applinks still opening only in browser, and I see, that app support the link, but it's unchecked.

Also command "adb shell pm get-app-links "com.myapp.android" returns

```
com.myapp.android:
ID: 893......
Signatures: [13:03....DA]
Domain verification state:
  www.myapp.com: legacy_failure
```

Why? Please help.

Comment: There seems to be at least one issue about this [in the Android issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204233247?pli=1)

Comment: There is also Domain verification state: www.myapp.com: legacy_failure. Could it be because of those bug too @Michael?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was in incorrect file syntax.
The correct is:

```
[
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "web",
      "site": "{siteurl}"
    }
  },
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.my.app.android",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "B4:...:9M"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.my.app.android",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "B4...9M"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.my.app.android.dev",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "BK...9Q"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: If a syntax error is not the causes, there are other suggestions to resolve the `legacy_failure` error here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68144323/app-links-legacy-failure-verification-error-on-android-12/70611053#70611053

Comment: Hi, I have only the last part in my JSON file. about dev build. and it's not working. Can you help me?

Comment: Sagar, you need to check every letter in your file. I my case there was "common.handle.handle_all_urls" ("handle" twice). Also check your ha256_cert_fingerprints, it should be exactly yours from Android Studio. Also you can investigate this link: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations , and this link generator and tester online: https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator

Comment: Where was this file? What this file is called ? Can you write that as well? It does not help for the people that do not have enough context (including me)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you already visit the following link: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing

Just a little bit improve your manifest to clean the code

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" tools:node="merge">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
<data android:host="${hostName}" android:pathPrefix="/auth/login" android:scheme="https"/>
```

Check your assetlinks.json file https://DOMAIN.well-known/assetlinks.json

I faced the issue with Apple M1 Chip an link working on intel based machines, I'm made the theory Android Studio not verifying the App Link on M1 Machines

Comment: Yes, I did it all. But it's still not working :)