# Android deep links legacy failure issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-12, android-deep-link

we need to verify app deep links in order to work on android 12. I have added the assetlinks.json as well as added autoverify in the intent filter with having a host as per the requirement.

```
[
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "web",
      "site": "https://proofing.example.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "web",
      "site": "https://www.example.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds",
      "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": “packangename,
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        “{Added cert fingerpinters here}”
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

When I test this through this command: "adb shell pm get-app-links package name", I am getting legacy_faiulre error.

Please let me know if anyone knows anything about this.

Comment: This Answer might help solve the issue- > https://stackoverflow.com/a/68144368/6826629

Comment: Thanks. it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `sha256_cert_fingerprints` is correct. Solved my issue.