# What are the changes need for working deeplink in Android 12

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking, android-12, android-deep-link

The deep linking feature of my app was working fine with Android 11. But it is not working in Android 12. I checked and followed several StackOverflow posts and some other blogs. But I am getting the links unchecked in the app details

[image]

If I manually check it, the deep linking will work.

I tried manual verification by using the documentation and getting `legacy_failure` error.
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#manual-verification

I followed this URL too https://doordash.engineering/2022/01/25/your-deep-links-might-be-broken-web-intents-and-android-12/comment-page-1/?unapproved=40015&moderation-hash=dc9e7df0845c5072330edc78f75ca497#comments .

Comment: Did you solve the issue ? we got the same problem.

Comment: This works for me. No custom scheme for autoVerify=true.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70611053/309740

Comment: Removing custom scheme saved me. Thanks @neobie!

Answer (score 4):

This approach should solve deeplink issue on android 12 above

**Automatic approach**

skip step 1 & 2

Go to Tools/ App Link Assistance and follow the step on the image

[image]

**Manual Approach**

Step 1: update all intent filters that can respond to an HTTP link with the android:autoVerify="true"

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Step 2: Create the assetlinks.json file and update your package and sha key

```
  //update package_name and sha256_cert_fingerprints with yours
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
  "namespace": "android_app",
  "package_name": "Your App’s package name", 
  "sha256_cert_fingerprints":  ["Your App’s SHA256 finger print"]
 }
```

}]

Step 3: Publishing the JSON verification file
Work with your infrastructure team to deploy the assetlinks.json file to the host

```
https://your domain.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

Be sure of the following:

- The assetlinks.json file is served with content-type application/json.
- The assetlinks.json file must be accessible over an HTTPS connection, regardless of whether your app's intent filters declare HTTPS as the data scheme.
- The assetlinks.json file must be accessible without any redirects (no 301 or 302 redirects).
- Do not publish your app with dev/test URLs in the manifest file that may not be accessible to the public (such as any that are accessible only with a VPN). A work-around in such cases is to configure build variants to generate a different manifest file for dev builds.